# How do I write queries to compare nodes and edges on different paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are new to Neo4j (and excited!) and I'm trying to apply Cypher to our problem. We have a query that matches paths but which needs to remove paths that involve any nodes or edges that were traversed on any other paths that originated from the same node or edge. Here's a test case:

```
CREATE (a1:A {name: 'a1'})-[ab1:AB {name: 'ab1'}]->(b1:B {name: 'b1'}),
       (a1)-[ab2:AB {name: 'ab2'}]->(b2:B {name: 'b2'}),
       (a2:A {name: 'a2'})-[ab3:AB {name: 'ab3'}]->(b1),
       (a2)-[ab5:AB {name: 'ab5'}]->(b3:B {name: 'b3'}),
       (a3:A {name: 'a3'})-[ab4:AB {name: 'ab4'}]->(b2),
       (a3)-[ab6:AB {name: 'ab6'}]->(b3),
       (a4:A {name: 'a4'})-[ab7:AB {name: 'ab7'}]->(b3);
```

Formatted for readability:

```
a1-[ab1]->b1
a1-[ab2]->b2
a2-[ab3]->b1
a2-[ab5]->b3
a3-[ab4]->b2
a3-[ab6]->b3
a4-[ab7]->b3
```

We want to find these paths: [A, AB, B, AB, A, AB, B, AB, A] (four steps). (Note: we don't care about edge directionality.) Here's my first try (our terminology: i_id = 'initial' and t_id = 'terminal').

```
MATCH p = (i_id:A)-[ab1:AB]-(b1:B)-[ab2:AB]-(a1:A)-[ab3:AB]-(b2:B)-[ab4:AB]-(t_id:A)
RETURN i_id.name, ab1.name, b1.name, ab2.name, a1.name, ab3.name, b2.name, ab4.name, t_id.name
ORDER BY i_id.name;
```

The result is reasonable, given Cypher's [Uniqueness](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html) feature:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| i_id.name | ab1.name | b1.name | ab2.name | a1.name | ab3.name | b2.name | ab4.name | t_id.name |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "a1"      | "ab1"    | "b1"    | "ab3"    | "a2"    | "ab5"    | "b3"    | "ab6"    | "a3"      |
| "a1"      | "ab1"    | "b1"    | "ab3"    | "a2"    | "ab5"    | "b3"    | "ab7"    | "a4"      |
| "a1"      | "ab2"    | "b2"    | "ab4"    | "a3"    | "ab6"    | "b3"    | "ab5"    | "a2"      |
| "a1"      | "ab2"    | "b2"    | "ab4"    | "a3"    | "ab6"    | "b3"    | "ab7"    | "a4"      |
| "a2"      | "ab3"    | "b1"    | "ab1"    | "a1"    | "ab2"    | "b2"    | "ab4"    | "a3"      |
| "a2"      | "ab5"    | "b3"    | "ab6"    | "a3"    | "ab4"    | "b2"    | "ab2"    | "a1"      |
| "a3"      | "ab4"    | "b2"    | "ab2"    | "a1"    | "ab1"    | "b1"    | "ab3"    | "a2"      |
| "a3"      | "ab6"    | "b3"    | "ab5"    | "a2"    | "ab3"    | "b1"    | "ab1"    | "a1"      |
| "a4"      | "ab7"    | "b3"    | "ab5"    | "a2"    | "ab3"    | "b1"    | "ab1"    | "a1"      |
| "a4"      | "ab7"    | "b3"    | "ab6"    | "a3"    | "ab4"    | "b2"    | "ab2"    | "a1"      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, we want additional filtering. Consider WHERE i_id.name = 'a2':

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| i_id.name | ab1.name | b1.name | ab2.name | a1.name | ab3.name | b2.name | ab4.name | t_id.name |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "a2"      | "ab3"    | "b1"    | "ab1"    | "a1"    | "ab2"    | "b2"    | "ab4"    | "a3"      |
| "a2"      | "ab5"    | "b3"    | "ab6"    | "a3"    | "ab4"    | "b2"    | "ab2"    | "a1"      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice how the first path contains ab4.name = "ab4", which is also found on the second path as ab3.name. Conversely, "ab2" is found on the second path as ab4.name and on the first path as ab3.name. In our application we want these two to 'cancel out' so that the query returns no matches for a2.

So finally, my question: How would you approach doing this in Cypher? Multiple queries is OK as long as they execute quickly :-) I'm brand new to Cypher, but some of the things I thought might be useful are (straw-clutching, here :-)

- comparing paths as collections (something like WHERE ab4.name NOT
  IN ...?)
- labeling/adding properties to items indicate the i_id and
  path they're located at?
- FOR EACH?
- UNWIND?
- GROUP BY?

We'd like to do as much in Cypher as possible, but if the answer is "You can't do that," then we'll pull the above candidate results into memory and finish processing there. Thanks very much!

Comment: In the a2 example, when you say 'cancel out', do you want only one of the pathways to return, or neither?

Comment: @NicoleWhite Neither of the paths should qualify, that is, no rows should come back for a2. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. After re-reading a few times I think I understand. I've worked up a solution but it's pretty inelegant. I'll type it up now.

Answer (score 2):

So I've worked up a solution using your second suggestion, which is to add properties to the relationships to indicate if they are on two or more pathways.

First, create a `traversed` property on each `AB` relationship and set it to `0`:

```
MATCH ()-[ab:AB]-()
SET ab.traversed = 0
```

Now I'm going to use the `a2` as the starting node for an example. This query finds all pathways from `a2` to another node with label `A` that is four steps long. The `traversed` property of each of the relationships is set to the count of times that relationship was encountered on a pathway.

```
MATCH p = (a2:A {name:'a2'})-[:AB*4]-(:A)
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS r
WITH r, COUNT(*) AS times_traversed
SET r.traversed = times_traversed
RETURN r.name, r.traversed
ORDER BY r.name
```

And we get the following output:

[image]

As you explain in your example, `ab2` and `ab4` are on both pathways and so their `traversed` property is `2`.

With these properties set on each relationship, you can filter the pathways to only the pathways whose sum of the `traversed` properties is equal to the path length, which is 4 in your case.

```
MATCH p = (a2:A {name:'a2'})-[:AB*4]-(:A)
WHERE REDUCE(traversal = 0, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | traversal + r.traversed) = LENGTH(p)
RETURN p
```

This returns no paths, since the sum of the `traversed` properties is `6` for both pathways, and not the required `4`.

But like I said, this is super inelegant and there is probably a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you *very* much for this, Nicole. I think it's an excellent direction for me to pursue.